# Is it One Way Function?

Tags: one-way-function

I am currently studying a course in cryptography, and I have this exercise about OWF.
[image]

[image]

I'm failing to prove that this is an inverter to f. Am I in the right direction at all?
Thank you!

Comment: Transcribe those as text, and use MathJax for mathematical notations (or ask others to edit them in for you), images take up a lot of bandwidth for people on cellular network.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $g$ is not an OWF. What does it mean for $g$? How can this knowledge about $g$ help You find a preimage of $f$? What does it mean about $f$ being OWP?

Answer (score 0):

What is the probability that the $x$ you got ( from your reduction ) is the correct pre-image of $y$ with $f$? I.e., $\Pr[f^{-1}(y) = x]$?

Comment: i thought its 1/2 but lets say n= 100. assume all permutations of {0,1}^n such that they contain 5 zeros are mapped to 1111100000. also assume f(1111110000)=1111100001 (6 4 zeros). now if (g^-1)(111110000) = 1111110000 then f^-1 is right at only one out of about 250 times.

Comment: I get it that that cannot be a one-way permutation but I can't prove it formally

Comment: let's say n=10 *